# Download and rename image file from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, image, hyperlink

I have an Excel file, in which the column A consist of links to images and Column B contains the required name of the image. What is the best way to download the images and rename them automatically as per the name give in Column B.

Comment: have you had a look here: http://analystcave.com/excel-downloading-files-using-vba/

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have taken a look at it, and it seems it might be able to solve a part of the problem. I will forward it to someone inhouse with more VBA experience than myself!

Comment: A friend needed an app that downloads all the items in the excel file, I developed an electron app that runs on your machine and downloads the assets in column A. But no renaming is done, I'll be adding features to the app, this feature sounds good to add. If you want to give it a try you can find it on github: https://github.com/btargac/excel-parser-processor

Answer (score 0):

A friend needed an app that downloads all the items in the excel file, I developed an electron based app that runs on your machine and downloads the assets in column A and renames it if column B is supplied. If you want to give it a try you can find it on github: github.com/btargac/excel-parser-processor